# Synchronize Elapsed Time counter in web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, time, synchronization, webrtc

I have a WebRTC React application where people join a session and have video call together. The challenge is I have a Elapsed Time counter at the bottom where you can see how long has the meeting going on. Now the challenge is, how can I build in a way all the users that have joined see the same values at the same time.
My current solution is. When joining the session. Get the elapsed time from the server like '00:34:10' and the do the +1 counter on the client side. But I am not sure if after 2 hours, if all the clients will be synchronized.

I don't wanna do polling and get the elapsed time each one second since I feel it will be very data consuming. Maybe there is no perfect solution but how do people tackle this.

Comment: Save the start time in GMT time in the server. As a client connects it just has to retrieve that time from the server. Then just calculate client side the difference between the current time and the starttime retrieved from the server with an interval.